# How can I add ether ether to my balance and return ether from it later?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am learning to create smart contracts, but I have encountered such a problem, I am trying to add ether to the balance of the smart contract but it does not work for some reason and the balance is always equal to 0. And my virtual wallet has not dropped the ether. I add my code.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract DepositContract {

    event Deposit(address indexed sender, uint256 amount);
//1000000000000000000 wei // 1 eth

    function invest() external payable {
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(msg.value);

        emit Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function balanceOf() public view returns(uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `invest()` function you're saying to transfer msg.value to calling address. The `transfer()` function, you must to use only when you want to transfer an amount to specific address.
If you want to deposit an amount inside your smart contract you only define a payable modifier inside signature function and put value inside 'VALUE' textbox present in '`DEPLOY AND RUN TRANSACTION`' section in **Remix IDE** and at this point you'll call `invest()` function.
Change your smart contract in this way:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract DepositContract {

    event Deposit(address indexed sender, uint256 amount);
    //1000000000000000000 wei // 1 eth

    function invest() external payable {
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function balanceOf() public view returns(uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```